# Function Parameter issue

Tags: java, android, generics

```
public class LoginRequest extends GsonRequest<HttpModel<Login>> {

     public LoginRequest(Map<String , String> params,Response.Listener<HttpModel<Login>> listener, Response.ErrorListener errlistener) {

            super(Method.POST,url,(HttpModel<Login>).class, null, params, listener, errlistener);
     }
}
```

Error in super fun call 2nd parameter 
the function expects **`Class<HttpModel<Login>>.class`**

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: @Jas when function expects `Class<HttpModel<Login>>.class`  type . how the function call looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Check your GsonRequest class. You are passing wrong parameters. you can check this link for help

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply i saw the link . my service responding always  with data `status` and `message` . `status` is 1 or 0 and `message` contains the model so i created a class `HttpModel` as `public class HttpModel<T> {

    int status;
    T  message;
}`

Comment: You are welcome. If you think it resolves your problem then you can upvote/accept the answer

Comment: ie, instead of `T` i am using `HttpModel<T>` .thus the error occured.